# Using FsCheck in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, fscheck

I am trying to use FsCheck 0.8.3 in Visual Studio 2010 for F#.
I have created a project, and wrote the example line:

```
let revRevIsOrig (xs:list<int>) = List.rev(List.rev xs) = xs
```

from the quick-start guide. After this, I added the FsCheck.dll to the references, and

```
open FsCheck
```

at the top.

When running, I recieve

> The namespace or module 'FsCheck' is not defined

Forgive me if the answer is obvious, but I'm quite new and don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: It seems VS 2010 doesn't recognize `FsCheck.dll` correctly. You could try to remove and re-add `FsCheck.dll` or reference the dll via NuGet. If FsCheck is referenced in the right way; you can do `Quick.Check revRevIsOrig` just fine.

Comment: No idea what's going on. But just for info: I recently used FsCheck 0.8.2 with Visual Studio 2010, without problems.

Comment: @pad, I've tried adding/removing the dll (and multiple versions of it); and have also installed it via nuget. The "open" command works fine, in fact, its necessary for Quick.Check revRevIsOrig to not throw errors. However at runtime, I still get the above error.

Comment: Is that the full error message? If it's an exception, what's the full stack trace? If it's not, then what is it? Unfortunately I don't have vs2010 around anymore to try, but I don't see a reason off the top of my head why it wouldn't work.